# regular expression not matching partially a string

Tags: regex

I have seen there has been already someone asking this question but the reply didn't work in my case. I have a reg exp structured like the below:

> `/regexp/(?i:mktg)`

to avoid character case conditions. I'll need to build up this expression containing "mktg" but not containing the words "round" **AND** "SMP" in any character case. Anyone willing to help?
I have tried already `/regexp/([^?i:SMP])` and `/regexp/^((?!SMP).)*$`, but those will still pull this string.

thanks,

Valeria

Comment: Try using this [Regular Expression tester](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: What crazy tool or environment makes you put `/regexp/` in front of your regex?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this should do the job:

```
^(?i)(?=.*mktg)((?!round|smp).)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
(?i)        : case insensitive
(?=         : start lookahead, zero-length assertion, make sure we have
  .*        : 0 or more any character
  mktg      : literally "mktg"
)           : end lookahead
(           : start group
  (?!       : start negative lookahead, zero-length assertion, make we DON'T have:
    round   : literally "round"
    |       : OR
    smp     : literally "smp"
  )         : end lookahead
  .         : any character
)*          : group must be repeated 0 or more times
$           : end of line
```

**Test cases:**

```
Match: mktg
Match: abc mktg xyz
No match: round mktg 
No match: SmP mktg 
No match: SPM ROUND
```

Comment: `(?i)^(?!.*(round|smp)).*?mktg`might be more efficient

Comment: @tripleee: May be, I haven't done benchmark.

Comment: I'm being modest; it avoids backtracking compared to yours but of course, in this isolated case, it probably doesn't matter much.